# How Java implement lazy initialization for HashMap?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, hashmap

For example I have a List: forumData.

```
List<HashMap<String, String>> forumData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
```

I now have to write 3 lines to insert the data as follows:

```
HashMap<String, String> _forum = new HashMap<String, String>();
_forum.put("ASDF", "ASDF");
forumData.add(_forum);
```

Can I do something like below?

```
forumData.add(new HashMap<String, String>("ASDF,"ASDF"));
```

?

Comment: What do you mean lazy? As that usually implies late evaluation.

Comment: "Lazy initialization" has nothing to do with the programmer being lazy to write code, it is an initialization that is delayed to the moment the data is actually required.